# Angular: ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for UserService

Tags: angular

my co-worker is in charge of the frontend, we have an Angular10 project, it was running normally.
then this error started showing without any noticeable changes made to the app. this is the code of the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { User } from './../models/user.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`);
    }
}
```

what's the reason of that? we checked very well and didn't find anything circular, I brought the project on my machine and tried to run it as a fresh environment, but still the same.

**UPDATE, MORE DETAILS:**

this is the console error:

```
ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for UserService
at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:1352)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11154)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:10979)
at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25053)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:10990)
at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25053)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:10990)
at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25053)
at Object.get (core.js:24767)
at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3296)
```

and this is the app module:

```
import { fontAwesomeIcons } from './font-awesome-icons';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular- fontawesome';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './user/footer/footer.component';

import { NgxWebstorageModule } from 'ngx-webstorage';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot(),
    /* JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: function tokenGetter() {
          return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4200'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['http://localhost:4200/auth/login']
      }
    }) */
  ],  
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(iconLibrary: FaIconLibrary){
    iconLibrary.addIcons(...fontAwesomeIcons);
  }
 }
```

Comment: More information such as the error stack and the app module would be helpful.

Comment: @garbear there isn't a stack actually, i upadated with the console log and some modules.

Comment: Unless environment or User are referencing UserService, it doesn't look like there is a circular dependency. Is the error really originating in this service?